# Unable read file in D3 to display graphs on webpage on Tomcat server

Tags: javascript, python, tomcat, d3.js

I working on populating a bar chart on a webpage using D3. I read a tsv file and use that data to generate the graphs. My code works perfectly fine if I run it on a python SimpleHTTPServer but when I test the same on a tomcat server I get the following error :

> ```
> mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial
> [[Prototype]] value using Object.create d3.v3.min.js:3:10397
>
> Unexpected value NaN parsing y attribute. d3.v3.min.js:1:0 
> Unexpected value NaN parsing height attribute.
> ```

I am keeping both the `tsv` files and the required `html/css/js` files in the same folder. What could be causing this issue ?

Comment: The `mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly` is a warning [you can ignore](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1805) for now.  The `Unexpected value`, though, I would guess is being caused by Tomcat serving the `tsv` file incorrectly.  In your browser dev tools, under network, what is that file being served as?

Comment: @Mark It says 'text/tab-separated-values' for file type under network. But I see a difference in the size of the data while comparing both the servers. When I hit the file URL, I directly get the content of the tsv file from tomcat server whereas when I try from the python SimpleHTTPServer it prompts me to download the file.

Comment: Hmm, strange, do you read the `tsv` with `d3.tsv("/path/to/tsv.tsv", function(error, data) { if (error) console.log(error); ... });`, any errors there?

Comment: @Mark I read the file like this where 'datafile' is the tsv file:            d3.tsv(datafile, function (error, data) {
                if (error) throw error;